# how to use the client_authenticated_user custom grant type on light-oauth2 token endpoint

Tags: oauth, light-4j

I am trying to use the custom grant type client_authenticated_user of light-oauth2 token service. The reason I cannot use standard grant types is due to my client need to talk to both legacy soap API and new restful API built on top of light-rest-4j. Today the client(webserver) does the authentication for users and we want to generate a token similar with authorization code grant type by passing the user profile to light-oauth2 token service. We have both client and light-oauth2 deployed on the same organization and the client is set up trusted client type on light-oauth2 client registration.

The question is how can I access token server to get JWT token using this custom grant type as this is not a standard flow. Do you have any examples or curl commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not a standard grant type in OAuth 2.0 specification, a lot of users are confused. To clarify this, I have created a tutorial and provide several curl command for the happy path.

https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/oauth/custom/